# Unity3d Roguelike 2D: How to expand on Enemy "OnCantMove" script to attack walls?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, roguelike

This is my first time asking a question here at StackOverflow.

I have finished the Unity 3D official "Roguelike 2D" tutorial, and trying to expand on it on my own. When the `Player` tries to walk into a wall, he damages it instead, eventually breaking through.

I have removed sounds and animator commands for clarity.

```
protected override void OnCantMove<T> (T component)
{
    Wall hitWall = component as Wall;
    hitWall.DamageWall (wallDamage);
}
```

And when the `Enemy` tries to walk into the `Player`, it damages him instead, hurting him.

```
protected override void OnCantMove <T> (T component)
{
    Player hitPlayer = component as Player;
    hitPlayer.LoseFood (playerDamage);
}
```

`playerDamage` is set by the Enemy script, and `wallDamage` is set by the Player script (meaning both are set by the one doing the damage.) `LoseFood` and `DamageWall` are set by the Player and the Wall scripts (meaning both are set by the one receiving the damage.)

I want the `Enemy` to be able to damage Walls, like the `Player` is. So, I tried changing the Enemy script's `OnCantMove` part to something like this:

```
protected override void OnCantMove<T> (T component)
{
    Wall hitWall = component as Wall;
    hitWall.DamageWall (wallDamage);
    Player hitPlayer = component as Player;
    hitPlayer.LoseFood (playerDamage);
}
```

and this:

```
protected override void OnCantMove<T> (T component)
{
    Wall hitWall = component as Wall;
    Player hitPlayer = component as Player;
    if (hitWall) {hitWall.DamageWall (wallDamage);}
    else if (hitPlayer) {hitPlayer.LoseFood (playerDamage);}
}
```

Neither worked the way I wanted them to do. I even tried to replace the `OnCantMove` function of the `Enemy` to be the same as when the `Player` hits the walls, but that only removed the ability the `Enemy` had to hit the `Player`, without enabling it to hit walls. What should I try next, to see if I can solve this problem?

If I manage to get this to work, I'm hoping I can continue to expand on this game in other ways as well, but I am very new at this. Thank you for any help and advice.

Comment: This question is more suited for [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the MoveEnemy-method of the enemy script. It calls `AttemptMove<Player>`, so it will only ever send in a player object to the OnCantMove-method. Not sure how I'd solve it, but you probably need to re-build a bit to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! I had also finished this tutorial and decided to expand the game to learn a bit more about Unity. Thanks to this challenge, I was able to re-factor the code and put it working as expected (see result [here](http://screencast.com/t/dS3daKgBEt))

Indeed, the issue was related to the `AttempMove<Player>` as [Jonatan Hedborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230631/jonatan-hedborg) pointed out.

Because of the generic type in `AttemptMove <T> (int xDir, int yDir)` function in `MovingObject.cs` I decided to make it return an integer to tell if it hit the mentioned component or not, likewise:

```
protected virtual int AttemptMove <T> (int xDir, int yDir)
where T : Component
{
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    bool canMove = Move(xDir, yDir, out hit);

    if (hit.transform == null)
        return MOVE_ATTEMPT_NO_HIT;

    T hitComponent = hit.transform.GetComponent<T>();

    if (!canMove && hitComponent != null)
    {
        OnCantMove(hitComponent);
        return MOVE_ATTEMPT_HIT;
    }

    return MOVE_ATTEMPT_NO_HIT;
}
```

`MOVE_ATTEMPT_HIT` and `MOVE_ATTEMPT_NO_HIT` are simply integer constants defined in `MovingObject.cs` as:

```
public const int MOVE_ATTEMPT_NO_HIT  = 0;
public const int MOVE_ATTEMPT_HIT     = 1;
```

Then it was just a simple matter of changing `MoveEnemy()` from `Enemy.cs` to check if the player was hit, if not then attempting to move him against a wall, likewise:

```
....
// Check if player was hit
int hitCode = AttemptMove<Player>(xDir, yDir);

// if player was hit, exit (don't forget to skip next move)
if (hitCode == MOVE_ATTEMPT_HIT)
{
    skipMove = true;
    return;
}

// else, check if a wall was hit
else if (hitCode == MOVE_ATTEMPT_NO_HIT)
    AttemptMove<Wall>(xDir, yDir);

skipMove = true;
}
```

Skipping a move, as in the tutorial's original code, is important. Otherwise, since the zombies can reach a point where they have no walls blocking the way, the player can really get stuck forever!